# How to read the data from .sql file in python without using connection parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a .sql file, when i am trying to read data from .sql file using python open() function it's reading the file only in readlines() method. And removing the \n and spaces, I am trying to convert into .txt file which is not happening. I don't have connection params.

```
sql_file = open('SQL_SCript.sql', 'r')
lines = sql_file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    line.strip()
with open('new_sql_script.txt', 'w') as new_sql_file:
    new_sql_file.write(str(lines))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to do is change the extension, why no just copy to a new file with the right name. An SQL file *is* still a text file.

```
import shutil

shutil.copyfile('SQL_SCript.sql', 'new_sql_script.txt')
```

---

If you're determined to do it by reading and writing, it looks like what you're currently doing is overwriting the last line on every iteration.

You want something like this:

```
with open('SQL_SCript.sql') as in_file:
    with open('new_sql_script', 'w') as out_file:
        for line in in_file:
            out_file.write(line)
```